# Profiling a game on android - Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to profile a game on real android device.

After I build and run it (with dev build, auto connect profiler and script debugging enabled) and setting android player instead of Editor in profiler/console options I can see that profiler window is working perfectly, but my console is not showing logs. (It did once (3 logs) but I cannot make it show logs again.)

Any suggestions of how I can make unity console show mobile logs?

Comment: Restart Unity.....

Comment: Simple solution, but works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can create new text document using notepad and insert the following text below and save it as .bat file:

> *Your Drive*:
>
> cd *location of the android sdk*
>
> adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG

so for example in my case it's:

> D:
>
> cd AndroidSDK\sdk\platform-tools
>
> adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG

from here you can see all the debug logs that comes from Unity